# SparkMagic PySpark3 session with Livy on Cloudera

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyterhub, livy

I am trying to run Jupyterhub pyspark kernel session with python3 witn Livy running on Cloudera cluster.

The spark session ends without any meaningful error, Livy logs have the following:

```
21/07/21 12:28:09 INFO yarn.Client: Submitting application application_1621851397242_29173 to ResourceManager
21/07/21 12:28:09 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1621851397242_29173
21/07/21 12:28:09 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1621851397242_29173 (state: ACCEPTED)
21/07/21 12:28:09 INFO yarn.Client:
   client token: N/A
   diagnostics: N/A
   ApplicationMaster host: N/A
   ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
   queue: root.users.username
   start time: 1626870489430
   final status: UNDEFINED
   tracking URL: http://hostname/proxy/application_1621851397242_29173/
   user: usenname
21/07/21 12:28:09 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
21/07/21 12:28:09 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-1483a0d9-2a27-4667-94c0-0320c6d2b0fa
21/07/21 12:28:09 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-a0c7670a-a2a1-46f0-bedd-83d0f4ea0086
```

Livy is running in yarn-cluster mode, and spark2-conf/spark-defaults.conf has a following configuration added:

> spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda-2020.11/bin/python
> spark.executorEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda-2020.11/bin/python

Anaconda-2020.11 is based on Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  4 2020, 07:30:14).

Pyspark kernel.json has a following configuration:

```
{
  "argv": [
    "python",
    "-m",
    "sparkmagic.kernels.pysparkkernel.pysparkkernel",
    "-f",
    "{connection_file}"
  ],
  "display_name": "PySpark",
  "language": "python"
}
```

What configuration I might be missing here? Should I use another jupyterhub kernel perhaps?

And last to add, everything works fine with another Anaconda enviroment based on Python 2.7.16 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 14 2019, 21:00:58). The issue occurs when I try to use newer Anaconda enviroment.

Answer (score 3):

After spending some time on that topic I have finally found a solution.

First of all spark, python and livy versions should be compatible.

For example, in my case I have spark 2.4.x on Cloudera, and that means I am limited to use python 3.6.x max. Despite spark documentation states that python 3.8.x is also supported by spark 2.4.x, it is not true. Python 3.8.x support in spark begins with spark 3.x.x.

Now for livy there is another story, the latest version of livy 0.7.1 supports spark 2.4.x at the time of writing this answer. Livy 0.7.1 and spark 3.x.x compatibility issue can be bypassed by recompiling livy scala code with 2.12 version.

Finally having all the components (spark, python and livy) aligned by compatible versions, in my case those were (2.4.x, 3.6.x, 0.7.1 accordingly), the pyspark session in jupyterhub was successfully created with python 3.6.x.

A couple of points to keep in mind:

- python should be updated on the Cloudera hosts
- if kernel.json uses 'python' command/alias, make sure 'python' alias mapped to python version 3.6.x on the Cloudera hosts
- mapping 'python' alias to python 3.6.x version, can potentially break things on Cloudera cluster
- no changes necessary on spark magic image or jupytehub kernels